# Caching results from a web API using with open

Tags: python, api, caching

I am using a lot of data returned from a WEB-api.The function below calls the API 22 times, decodes and loads json into python format. Then I store the results in a big list of 22 pages with each 100 art objects as data.

```
fourteen_list = return_14th_century_works_list()
```

To limit the necessary API-calls, I want to build a function that stores this list as a file if it is not present, and when it is present I want to load the file from my computer. I came up with the following:

```
with open('fourteenth_century_list.txt', 'w') as fourteenth_century_file:
    print(fourteen_list, file=fourteenth_century_file)

try:
    with open('fourteenth_century_list.txt', 'r') as fourteenth_century_file:
        fourteenth_list_cache = fourteenth_century_file.read()  
        count_objects(fourteenth_list_cache) 
except FileNotFoundError:
    fourteenth_list = return_14th_century_works_list() Calls API again
    count_objects(fourteen_list)
```

I use the count_objects function to check if everything still works, but the file that is opened in the try block doesn't seem to return in the same way I saved it; When I run this code, the function call in the try-block returns a type-error. For me this is an indication that the file opened from disk is in a somewhat different format then if I load it directly from the API.

When i call the function count_objects() with the non-cached version of my list, so fourteen_list in this case,works fine.

**Does with_open(filename, 'w') and then with_open(filename, 'r') mutate your data, and if not what am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: correct the indentation first please :-)

Comment: @NimishBansal mb

Comment: using with to open the file ensures that file will be closed as soon as with block ends

Comment: What are the type of objects held by the list - are they `dict`s?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes, they are dicts. The API returns pages of JSON data, when I check it in my browser this data looks like a dictionary, and after I deserialize (With data.decode('utf-8) and then json.loads(data.decoded), and do a type-check on the pages it returns 'dict'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when you `print` the list of dictionaries to a file, you create a string representation of the list. You then read that string back and pass it to `count_objects()`, but that falls over because it expects a list of dictionaries, not a big string.

Rather than printing, a better approach would be to serialize the list to back JSON - which would preserve its structure. You also want to write the list to the cache in the `except` block *after* you've retrieved the data from the API.

```
import json

try:
    with open('fourteenth_century_list.json', 'r') as fourteenth_century_file:
        fourteenth_list_cache = json.load(fourteenth_century_file)
        count_objects(fourteenth_list_cache) 
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Calls API again
    fourteenth_list = return_14th_century_works_list() 
    count_objects(fourteen_list)

    # Cache the API data
    with open('fourteenth_century_list.json', 'w') as fourteenth_century_file:
        json.dump(fourteen_list, fourteenth_century_file)
```

Comment: So when printing python data-structures to a file by using with open, are they always converted to a string representation? Would it have been better to use something like shelve here?  

It is indeed much more logical to  only cache _after_ trying to open, thinking mistake from my part (am still learning). Thanks for this very comprehensive answer sir =)

Comment: Yes `print` will just output the string representation of whatever is passed to it. Using `shelve` (or `pickle`) would also work, although keeping the format as JSON means the file is human readable should you need to ever edit it with a text editor.